# std::back_insert_iterator in C++17

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++17

As shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) `std::back_insert_iterator` in pre- C++17 inherits from `std::iterator` while it doesn't in C++17. What is the reason for this change?

Comment: std::iterator<> is being deprecated http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator

Comment: And since the next logical question is "Why deprecate `std::iterator`?", a rationale can be found here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html

Answer (score 6):

`std::iterator` is a convenience. It provides a handful of typedefs that code that uses iterators find useful. The preferred mechanism these days is `std::iterator_traits`, which is more flexible.

When an iterator is, in fact, a pointer it can't inherit from `std::iterator`, so `iterator_traits` has always been the way to get those typedefs. Having the typedefs in iterator types that are classes but not in iterator types that are pointers means that generic code can't use those members. Having them is minimally useful, and they're going away.

Comment: To make explicit what Pete said, `std::iterator` does not have any data members or any member functions. It just provides some nested typedefs.  As long as the information in the typedefs is available (and `std::iterator_traits` is the mechanism for getting it), then whether or not the iterators actually inherit to get the typedefs or declare them themselves makes no difference.